# Grails Spring Security Authorization Events

Tags: grails, logging, spring-security

I'm using Grails 2.3.6 with the Spring Security 2.0-RC2 plugin. I've been tasked with logging security related events for auditing purposes. I've created an event listener that implements ApplicationListener, and this makes it easy enough to log login failures, etc. However, I also want to log authorization failures, i.e. user tries to access a resource they're not allowed to access and things of that nature. How can I accomplish this? I can't seem to find anything related to what I need to do in order to get this type of stuff logged.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just implement an ApplicationListener in the same manner as the Authentication event listener and that'll do it.